# Как настроить проброс всего трафика с определенного интерфейса через Tor?

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables

Всем привет.

Нужна помощь в настройке нетфильтра для проброса трафика с определенного интерфейса через тор. Конфигурация уже есть, но в ней есть две проблемы:

- HTTPS-соединения сбрасываются (connection refused)
- DNS не работает

Вот [ссылка на конфиги ebtables/iptables](https://gist.github.com/vanufryiuk/7821d56fd236399849399a5882388993), где

- wlp3s0 - интерфейс, трафик с которого нужно пустить через тор
- br0 - бридж между интерфейсами локальной сетки (в т.ч. wlp3s0)
- eno1 - смотрит в интернет
- 9051 - порт прозрачного прокси тора
- 9053 - dns-порт тора

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Увидел у вас в профиле, что `Текущий стэк хобби-проектов - F#`. В [SO чате по F#](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) поднялся вопрос о [русскоязычном F#-сообществе](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35608815#35608815). Сообщаю через комментарии, так как не нашел систему личных сообщений и решил, что возможно вам это будет интересно. В любом случае хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение на этот счет.

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете правило перенаправления пакетов с порта 53 на 9053, но у вас нет правила разрешающего входящие пакеты от сервера (ответы). Ответы тоже с 9053 будут приходить? Тогда вам нужно такое правило - `-A INPUT -p udp --dport 9053 -j ACCEPT`

Насчёт HTTPS - этот протокол использует порт 443, а у вас разрешены пакеты лишь от 80-го порта (HTTP). Дополните ваше правило таким образом - `-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443,8888,8889 -j ACCEPT`

---

Дополнение:
Не помогло для DNS? А что насчёт HTTPS? С ним проблема решилась? И вы пробовали использовать журналирование операций? К примеру таким образом - назначаете правилам действия LOG_ACCEPT/LOG_REJECT, а затем описываете их примерно таким образом:

`-A LOG_ACCEPT -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT:ACCEPT:" --log-level 6 --log-uid
-A LOG_ACCEPT -j ACCEPT`

`-A LOG_REJECT -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT:REJECT:" --log-level 6 --log-uid
-A LOG_REJECT -j REJECT`

(опции по вкусу)

Comment: Боюсь, это не помогло. Правило, разрешающее доступ к этим портам предназначено только для подключения к самому шлюзу, не для ответа. Уже установленые соединения должны обрабатываться правилами -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT и -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstatus EXPECTED,SEEN_REPLY,ASSURED,CONFIRMED -j ACCEPT. И это работает, когда подключение делается не через тор.

Comment: @Fynivx - ответил в ответе %). А то в комментариях форматирования нет.